# Why ubuntu distribution?

Tags: 14.04, mint, custom-distributions, elementary

Why other distributions such as `mint`, `elementary`,... wait always `ubuntu` to release, so they could release their own distributions?

Comment: You should ask that on a mint forum ;)

Comment: Because those distributions rely on Ubuntu for testing and packaging.

Comment: Please mail the developers of the respective distros for an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They modify each release of Ubuntu to arrive at their own releases. Thus, even though there are development versions, since their work is dependent on (but not part of) the Ubuntu release cycle, there's always a gap between a release of Ubuntu and the corresponding releases of Linux Mint and others. Since they base themselves off Ubuntu, they have to ensure that package version and other changes should be reflected properly. For example, Debian voted to chose `systemd` as the default `init` system, and Ubuntu followed soon. Now, in the next release, Ubuntu will pick up the changes that have been made for `systemd` compatibility from Debian `jessie` and apply them to Ubuntu. The others will then use this release to work on.

Note, for instance, LMDE (Linux Mint Debian Edition): It is based on the Debian `testing`, which is a rolling-release distribution. In a rolling distribution, you don't have discrete releases, but a steady stream of updates. Linux Mint discretizes these packages into tested update packs, but not new releases as such. Thus, LMDE has nothing to do with Ubuntu's release cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Those distributions are Ubuntu based. They must wait for Ubuntu release to start build their distributions on top of it.

Comment: That exactly is my question, I know they are ubuntu based, but why they can't do their own distributions without ubuntu?

Comment: If they did their "own distribution" there would be more work as they would have to first get the source code and package it into a .deb They would then have to test to make sure everything was stable and debuged and report bugs upstream. Using Ubuntu saves work and allows the developers to focus on modifications and customization. Try it yourself - Build a distro starting with http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/. Be sure to include packages and a repository for your users.

Comment: i think mr.bodhi is correct

Comment: They can, they don't see a good reason to do that.